# Xcode 9.2 Unable to capture view hierarchy and could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

im getting this warning while debugging the app:

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

Also i can't capture view hierarchy, getting this kind of error:

> Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy.
>
> Details:  Log Title: Exception gathering debug hierarchy information.
>
> Log Details: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Meanwhile my colleagues has no problems with the same devices.

Debugging on devices with ios 10, 11; Xcode 9.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Try commenting out methods in your views until it works. The problem is that the view debugger calls a lot of extraneous methods, and crashes if one of them goes sour. Happened to me with `description`.

Comment: And file a bug report with Apple, please.